# xsl: for-each loop unexpected result in conditional test

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion

Consider this recursive XSLT template:

```
<xsl:template name="SUBREPORT_FIELDS" >
  <xsl:for-each select="current()/section/@name">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="current()/section/@name = $pSectionName">
        <xsl:call-template name="FieldSezione"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="FIELDS"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="SUBREPORT_FIELDS"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

And the following XML input document:

```
<box name="box3">
  <section name="sEmicrania">
    <box name="box4">
      <treecombobox name="tc"/>
      <textmemo name ="tm"/>
    </box>
    <box name="box4">
      <section name="sZona">
        <box name="box5">
          <label name="label1"/>
          <textmemo name="tmZona"/>
        </box>
      </section>
    </box>
  </section>
</box>
```

The variable $pSectionName will have as its value either "sEmicrania" or "sZona"; these are the values of the attribute "name" of the two "<section>" elements.

When the variable $pSectionName has the value sEmicrania, the template correctly evaluates the conditional test as true, but if the variable has the value "sZona" the test is evaluated as false.

I expect the test to return true in both cases.

Comment: Please post a **reproducible** example - see: [mcve]

Comment: I think you need to change `current()/section/@name = $pSectionName` just to `section/@name = $pSectionName`. `current()` is not the same as `.` even though in most places they behave the same way

Comment: What do you mean by "passing the variable"?  Your template is not set up to take a parameter.

Comment: You don't show how `pSectionName` is being set; how confident are you that you know its value?  (No offense intended, but you wouldn't be the first to be confused by the immutability of XSLT variables.)  Have you tried inserting `<xsl:message> The value of pSectionName is <value-of select = "$pSectionName"/> </xsl:message>` into the template to see what the processor thinks the value is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your template as it currently stands is not going to output anything, even in the case of `pSectionName` being set to "sEmicrania"

You start off by doing this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="current()/section/@name">
```

But this will only select anything if your current node is a `box` element. If this is the case, then within the `xsl:for-each` construct, the context will then be the `name` attribute. But then you have your test...

```
<xsl:when test="current()/section/@name = $pSectionName">
```

But `current()` in this case is the `name` attribute you are positioned on. This does not have a child called `section`, and so this test is false.

Instead, the `xsl:otherwise` is called to recursively call the template. This does not change the context, so you are still positioned on the `name` attribute. Therefore, the `xsl:for-each` this time will select nothing, and so nothing gets output.

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but I don't think you necessarily need a recursive template here. If you are simply trying to select the `section` element with a matching name, you can just do something like this

```
<xsl:template match="box">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//section[@name = $pSectionName]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section">
   <!-- Do what you need to do here -->
</xsl:template>
```